# Entity Framework adds extra field in database. and adds both members of composite key

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm struggling with composite keys and extra fields being generated by Entity Framework. I have a question about something which I think is odd.

Let's say I have a one to many relationships with these classes:

File (dossier)

```
[Table("Dossier")]
public class Dossier
{
    [Key]
    public string Dossiernummer { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string Dossierversie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Dossierreferentie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Relatienr { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Artikel> Artikels { get; set; } ();

}
```

And my artikel (article) class:

```
[Table("Artikel")]
public class Artikel
{
    [Key]
    public string Artnr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string ArtVersie { get; set; }

    public string ArtOmschrijving { get; set; }

    public Dossier Dossier { get; set; }

    public string Dossiernummer { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using migrations and a code first approach. For some reason using migrations creates a dossiernummer1 column in the artikel table. I don't understand why and would like it gone. Does anyone know how?

Another thing which I prefer not to have is the second primary key in my artikel table. It puts both keys from the dossier table in the artikel table yet I only want to use Dossiernummer as a foreign key. Do you know how to change this?

When getting all the dossiers from the context I notice something odd as well. When I look into a dossier object the artikels list is empty, even though data exists in the database for that. Is it normal you have to initialize it yourself?

Thanks for any help and info in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: Please always add the appropriate EF version tag.

Comment: Seeing your model, you should split `Dossier` into two tables: `Dossier` (only having `Dossiernummer` as primary key and a 1:n relationship to `Artikel`) and something like `DossierVersie`, storing all versions (1:n) of a Dossier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use fluent API for set relations and add `ColumnAttribute` to order keys :

```
[Table("Artikel")]
public class Artikel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Artnr { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ArtVersie { get; set; }

    public string ArtOmschrijving { get; set; }

    public Dossier Dossier { get; set; }

    public string Dossiernummer { get; set; }

}

[Table("Dossier")]
public class Dossier
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Dossiernummer { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Dossierversie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Dossierreferentie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Relatienr { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Artikel> Artikels { get; set; }
}
```

in your dbcontext override `OnModelCreating` method:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        builder.Entity<Dossier>()
               .HasMany(x => x.Artikels)
               .WithOne(a => a.Dossier)
               .HasForeignKey(a => new { a.Dossiernummer, a.Artnr });


        builder.Entity<Artikel>()
        .HasKey(x => new {x.Artnr,x.ArtVersie});

        builder.Entity<Dossier>()
        .HasKey(x => new {x.Dossiernummer,x.Dossierversie});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, It unfortunately seems however that modelbuilder has no withrequired method yet in asp.net core.

Answer (score 0):

Dossiernummer1:
Artikel has a Dossier. EF knows an K relationship must be set up. This requires that the PK of Dossier must be included in Artikel and wants to add it. It finds you've already put in a field with that name (what for it has no idea) and so it adds it as Dossiernummer1. You should not add Dossiernummer to Artikel - unless you you actually need one for something else - as the only reason it's there is to be an FK. EF will take care of that for you.

Adding Dossierversie to Artikel:
It thinks that the PK of Dossier is Dossiernummer + Dossierversie, and so to point to the correct Dossier it must have both of tem. I don't use code-first so I can't advise you on a) how to specify a PK and another, separate index (I assume that's what you want) versus a compound PK (which is what you appear to have).

Dossier.Artikels is empty: That's the way EF works, known as lazy loading. It gets the 'root' objects by not anything owned by them at first. Once your code accesses an Artikels collection it should load them (for that Dossier) at that point. This prevents EF pulling in what could be a large percentage of your database Imaging an ECommerce system. Getting a Customer list would pull in all Orders related to cutomers in that list; all order lines owned by those orders; all Product data related to the products on those order lines and so on. This would not be a good thing. Instead it just gets the things you've specifically mentioned and then pulls in related items as needed.

Incidentally, when looking as an unloaded collection as an attribute of the owner (e.g. looking at Artikels on a loaded Dossier), the debugger in VS tells me that examining the collection will result in it being loaded and gives me the option to continue or not.